# Blogdown: dates of entries appear in english, but needed in spanish

Tags: r, blogdown

I have set my language variable to es for spanish, but keep seeing the text for dates in english.

```
baseurl = "/"
title = "omargonzalesdiaz"
theme = "hugo-universal-theme"
languageCode = "es-es"
# Site language. Available translations in the theme's `/i18n` directory.
defaultContentLanguage = "es"
```

> Do I need to change something else?

[image]

website: http://omargonzalesdiaz.rbind.io

Github: https://github.com/OmarGonD/omargonzalesdiaz

Comment: Can you give this a try: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/parsing-dates-in-templates/603/12. Hugo says localized dates are not supported but offers a workaround: https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/#customize-dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but this is what I did and so far, it worked

```
languageCode = "es-es"
defaultContentLanguage = "es-es"
```